# Align vertical lists in html

Tags: html, css, alignment

Hello I am making a bar graph using only php and html. The graph must show the score for each team . This is my code:

```
<?php 

    $teams = get_teams();
?>

    <div id = "graph">
        <table>
            <tr>
    <?php
    foreach($teams as $team)

    {
        $name = $team['name'];
        $score= $team['score'];
        $height = $team['height'];

        <td>
            <ul id = "graph-list">
                <li class = "graph">
                    <img = src="<?php echo url_for('images/bar.png');?>" height ="<?php echo $height?>" width = "18" alt = ""/><br /><?php echo $score;?></li>
                <li class = "graph" id = "s"> <?php echo $name; ?></li>
            </ul>
        <td>

<?php }?>
```

And the stylesheet I am using is:

```
li.graph{
    display: inline-block;
    float: bottom;
    text-align: bottom;
    list-style:none outside none;
    margin-right: 12px;
    font-size: 12px;

}

li#s{
    margin: -9px;
    -moz-transform-rotate: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

div#graph{
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}

ul#graphlist {

  list-style: none;
  float: bottom;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}
```

However my graph is like:

[image: Broken graph]

What can I do so that the bars all start at the same y axis value and they don't kind of irregularly float like in my picture?

Comment: @executable I cant share a copy of the executable file I am sorry.

Comment: @04FS I know but I am very new to css :/. Anyway I have tried to add a vertical-align: middle attribute but nothing changed... I also tried to set it to top just for the sake of trying but still got the same result.

Comment: When asking about CSS you need to show the actual rendered HTML markup, not your server-side code. CSS doesn't care what's on the server. Use your browser's document inspector to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quickly knocked this up to give you an idea of how you could go about it using flexbox.

https://codepen.io/1amShaw/pen/OJJGzMo

I think you could possible change your Markup, so each score has it's own list item:

```
<ul class="graph-list">
  <li>
      <div class="graph-block">
        <div class="graph-block__bar" style="height: 100%"></div>
        <div class="graph-block__score">1800</div>
        <div class="graph-block__name"><span>Mr Smith</span></div>
      </div>
   </li>
  <li>
      <div class="graph-block">
        <div class="graph-block__bar" style="height: 50%"></div>
        <div class="graph-block__score">900</div>
        <div class="graph-block__name"><span>Mrs Jones</span></div>
      </div>
  </li>
  <li>
      <div class="graph-block">
        <div class="graph-block__bar" style="height: 10%"></div>
        <div class="graph-block__score">100</div>
        <div class="graph-block__name"><span>Mr Bloggs</span></div>
      </div>
  </li>
  <li>
      <div class="graph-block">
        <div class="graph-block__bar" style="height: 37%"></div>
        <div class="graph-block__score">370</div>
        <div class="graph-block__name"><span>Mr Mcallister</span></div>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then as far as the CSS goes, you can use flexbox to achieve your goal.

```
.graph-list {
  background-color: #DDD;
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 20px 140px;
}

.graph-list li {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.graph-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.graph-block__bar {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto auto 0;
  width: 40px;
}

.graph-block__score {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.graph-block__name {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(30px) translateY(-50%);
  transform-origin: left top;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

You could also maybe use CSS gradients to create the bar, rather than an image, just in case you want to maybe animate it or something at some point?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting them in a flex-box container `display:flex;` and setting `align-items:flex-end;`

Here is an example:

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-end;
}
.container .item{
  width:50px;
  margin:0 10px;
  text-align:center;
}
.container .item .bar{
  width:30px;
  height:10px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:linear-gradient(to left, blue,skyblue,cyan);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bar" style="height:70px">
    </div>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bar" style="height:100px">
    </div>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="bar" style="height:200px">
    </div>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```